# Azure Data Factory 'Pending Validation'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

I created some pipelines in my Azure Data Factory service to move data from SQL Tables to Azure Tables. But they never start running. Instead, the source data sets remain `pending validation` even after I click the `run` button in Azure Portal. I have already checked the `external` properties, which are all set as `true`. I wonder if there are any other possible reasons.

And here is my table source

```
{
    "name": "TableSrc",
    "properties": {
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "linkedServiceName": "LinkedService-AzureSql",
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "myTable"
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Month",
            "interval": 1
        },
        "external": true,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this trying to set up a pipeline to run daily, and thought that I could use the "anchorDateTime" availability property and I was able to do this but you have to set the `"frequency"` property of the `"availability"` section in the dataset to the lowest level of granularity that you want to specify.  That is, if you want something to run at 6:30pm UTC every day, your dataset needs to look like this (because you are specifying a time at the minute-level):

```
"availability": {
    "frequency": "Minute",
    "interval": 1440,
    "anchorDateTime": "2016-01-27T18:30:00Z"
}
```

and the `"scheduler"` portion of the pipeline needs to be something like:

```
"scheduler": {
    "frequency": "Minute",
    "interval": 1440,
    "anchorDateTime": "2016-01-27T18:30:00Z"
}
```

This will run every 1440 minutes (i.e. every 24 hours).  I hope that it helps somebody else out since the Microsoft documentation contradicts itself on this topic (or at least is misleading):

> For a daily schedule, if you set anchorDateTime = 10/20/2014 6 AM means that the scheduling will happen every day at 6 AM.

This is actually not true, and two lines later it says:

> If the AnchorDateTime has date parts that are more granular than the interval, then the more granular parts will be ignored. For example, if the interval is hourly (frequency: hour and interval: 1) and the AnchorDateTime contains minutes and seconds, then the minutes and seconds parts of the AnchorDateTime will be ignored.

This second part is what I think we're running into and why I suggested the strategy above.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894092.aspx

Comment: This is alright for time intervals whose length doesn't change, but may not be viable for something like "Month" since you would have to specify a number of days as the interval.

Comment: Instead of working with an anchor, you can also work with an offset property to the availability. I believe that taking the the answer of TheSchmoe and adding an offset would provide a solution. See also: [Dataset Availability properties](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-datasets/#Availabilit)

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason... It will wait for the next rounded month to start. Which means it will start at the first day of next month, and no way to manually trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem. Turns out that I had not specified the start time of the pipeline according to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want your pipeline to be run, update active periods to dates in the past. You can do it using below powershell command

set-AzureDataFactoryPipelineActivePeriod -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineName $PipelineName -StartDateTime $DateInPast -EndDateTime $DateOneDayLessInPast -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Force

Comment: Yes, that was my case. Just for information, it is not necessary to change the date via powershell, one can simply edit the pipeline JSON in the portal.